# Angular TSLint: Continue to next step even if Errors

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, tslint, angular10

I am receiving the following errors when running TSLint in Azure Devops Build Pipeline.
I want to make the build pipeline continue to next step, even if there are lint error.
How can this be resolved?

**Command Line:**

```
  - script: |
      npm run lint > tsLintReport.txt
    displayName: 'ng lint'
```

**Error:**

```
Lint warnings found in the listed files.
Lint errors found in the listed files.
Lint errors found in the listed files.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ipts@1.0.0 lint: `ng lint`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ipts@1.0.0 lint script.
```

Comment: The linting failed, because there are linting errors in some files. Check `tsLintReport.txt` for them.

Comment: I want to make the build pipeline continue, even if there are lint error. can this be done cc @AlexBiro

Comment: You have to configure your CI to ignore the results of the linting, I am not familiar with the Azure CI. And actually, I don't suggest to that, because that way you will probably never fix those issues, and they will just keep piling up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add `continueOnError`:

```yaml
  - script: |
      npm run lint > tsLintReport.txt
    displayName: 'ng lint'
    continueOnError: true
```

it will not break the build but the build finishes with issues.

Comment: Is there a way to view the lint errors or warnings in the summary tab?

Comment: Summary tab supports markdown format. So you need to format it. But you can try with logging command as it is shown here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#uploadsummary-add-some-markdown-content-to-the-build-summary you can try also upload file as `uploadfile`

Comment: Thanks Madej, that's good to know. Also I've found there are formatters for Eslint already (eslint-formatter-vso), so planning to go down that path instead.

Comment: Cool! Can you consider upvoting my answer if it was helpful for you?

Answer (score -1):

try running "npm run lint -- --fix" that would fix the lint errors automatically

Comment: Such changes should never be done in a CI pipeline

Comment: @NicoHaase If we get issue with angular code in CICD pile we can use this command with the angular code if we have some blank space or in place of === if we added == it will resolve automatically

Comment: What do you mean by "it will resolve automatically"? Would the pipeline commit these changes to your repository?